# How to define custom url while hostingdotnet core 2.0 application in Kestrel

Tags: kestrel-http-server, .net-core-2.0

I am hosting my angular application using DotNet Core 2.0 and here is my hosting configuration in program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace Samples.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(options=>{
                     options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback,5050);
                })
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

I overrided default port number 5000 of Kestrel using options.So http://localhost:5050 is working but how can I make a custom host url something like http://localhost:5050/samples working as well?

**I tried UseUrls which didn't work**. Thanks for help.

Comment: For that you need routing. Have a look at [Routing Asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: This is angular application, the first default route will be app.

Comment: However you have the Startup class where you can define the routing in the Configure method.